# Can there be precession without angular momentum?

Tags: angular-momentum, magnetic-moment, precession

In a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_and_angular_momentum) article it is said:

> The *magnetic moment has a close connection with angular momentum*
>   called the gyromagnetic effect. This effect is expressed on a
>   macroscopic scale in the Einstein-de Haas effect... In particular, when a magnetic moment is subject to a
>   torque in a magnetic field that tends to align it with the applied
>   magnetic field, the moment precesses (rotates about the axis of the
>   applied field). This is a **consequence of the concomitance of magnetic
>   moment and angular momentum,** that in case of charged massive particles
>   corresponds to the concomitance of charge and mass in a particle.

This seems to signify that precession requires angular momentum $L$ and  there can be no precession if there is no (mechanical) $L$ associated to the magnetic moment. If this is correct, can you explain in detail why it is so? E.g., as a current loop has a magnetic field and magnetic moment, but no angular momentum, it can't precess? In an external field it will only rotate just to align to the applied field?

Comment: In practice the current loop would have angular momentum as charge carriers are massive particles see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOdboRYf1hM). In theory, you can of course have your current consist of positive charges going in one and negative in the other direction or zero mass charge carriers.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you read the article on [precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession)?

Comment: @mikuszefski, of course, gravity acts on mass and a top precesses witout magnetic moment, B field acts on magnetic moment , why do we need also L with $\mu$ when a B field is on? Actually you haven't yet explicitly confirmed whether L is necessary along with $\mu$, have you?

Comment: @mikuszefski, ...also, a top start precessing when L decreases, whereas $\mu$ is stable and electron L is too, since it is *intrisic*. Why does it precess and why L is needed?

Comment: Well, it was not my intention to answer your question, yet. Up to now I tried to get some insight in your thinking only. To start going in the direction of an answer: Precession is the rotation of a rotational axis. It is therefore required, hence, that something is rotating. And you need a physical quantity reflecting this. A theoretical current is not sufficient as this could be positive turning in one, or negative turning in the other direction.

Comment: @mikuszefski, if there is a magnetic moment, as you earlier acknowledged, something must be spinning. If it is DC there is only one direction.

Comment: Why do you think that a magnetic moment requires something spinning? And no, DC does not define the direction, that is only a technical definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44720/discussion-between-mikuszefski-and-user104372).